# Is there a way to call the tableview again from qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to output the db value corresponding to that value in the table view when the button for that value is pressed.
It is possible to receive the db from the cpp file and input it into a vector, but I do not know how to call the table view where this vector value will be entered again when the button is pressed....

producttable.h

```
#ifndef PRODUCTTABLE_H
#define PRODUCTTABLE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include "sqlquerymodel.h"

class ProductTable : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    enum TableRoles{
        TableDataRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        HeadingRole
    };

public:
    explicit ProductTable(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

signals:
    void qmlSignal(QString msg);

public slots:
    void cppSlot(const QString &msg);

private:
    QVector<QVector<QString>> productTable;
    SqlQueryModel *db;
    QString c_name=nullptr;

};

#endif // PRODUCTTABLE_H
```

producttable.cpp

```
#include "producttable.h"
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

ProductTable::ProductTable(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel{parent}
{
    productTable.clear();

    QSqlQuery query;
    QString c_code;

    if(c_name==nullptr){

        query.prepare("select product_name, product_sale from product");
        query.exec();

        QVector<QString> e;

        int i=0;
        while(query.next()){
            e.append(query.value(0).toString() + "\n" + query.value(1).toString() + "원");
            i++;
            if(i==4){
                productTable.append(e);
                e.clear();
                i=0;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        query.prepare("select cartegory_code from cartegory where cartegory_name = '"+c_name+"'");
        query.exec();
        query.next();
        c_code=query.value(0).toString();

        query.prepare("select product_name, product_sale from product where cartegory_code = "+c_code+"");
        query.exec();

        QVector<QString> e;

        int i=0;
        while(query.next()){
            e.append(query.value(0).toString() + "\n" + query.value(1).toString() + "원");
            i++;
            if(i==4){
                productTable.append(e);
                e.clear();
                i=0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int ProductTable::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const{
    return productTable.size();
}

int ProductTable::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const{
    return productTable.at(0).size();
}

QVariant ProductTable::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
    switch(role){
        case TableDataRole:
            return productTable.at(index.row()).at(index.column());
        case HeadingRole:
            if(index.row()==0){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ProductTable::roleNames() const{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TableDataRole] = "producttabledata";
    roles[HeadingRole] = "heading";
    return roles;
}

void ProductTable::cppSlot(const QString &msg){
    c_name=msg;

    productTable.clear();
    QString c_code;
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("select cartegory_code from cartegory where cartegory_name = '"+c_name+"'");
    query.exec();
    query.next();
    c_code=query.value(0).toString();

    query.prepare("select product_name, product_sale from product where cartegory_code = "+c_code+"");
    query.exec();

    QVector<QString> e;

    int i=0;
    while(query.next()){
        e.append(query.value(0).toString() + "\n" + query.value(1).toString() + "원");
        i++;
        if(i==4){
            productTable.append(e);
            e.clear();
            i=0;
        }
    }
    //qDebug() << productTable;

    //QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    //engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    //productTable.refresh();
    qDebug()<< c_name;

    //beginResetModel();
    //endResetModel();
}
```

main.qml

```
TableView {
                        id: producttableview
                        x: 5
                        y: 5
                        width: 380
                        height: 435
                        columnSpacing: 10
                        rowSpacing: 80
                        clip: true

                        property var columnWidths: [87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5]
                        columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return columnWidths[column] }


                        property alias tableVerticalBar: productVerticalBar

                        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                            id: productVerticalBar
                            policy:ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
                        }

                        model: ProductTable {}

                        delegate: Rectangle{
                            height: 100

                            Button {
                                width: 88
                                height: 115

                                Text {
                                    text: producttabledata
                                    font.pointSize: 9
                                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                                }
                                onClicked: {
                                    //saletext2.text = categorytabledata
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
```

When clicking a button in the table view below, I want the table view above to change to the vector value changed in cpp.

```
 TableView {
                        x: 5
                        y: 5
                        width: 380
                        height: 100
                        columnSpacing: 10
                        rowSpacing: 10
                        clip: true

                        property var columnWidths: [65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
                        columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return columnWidths[column] }

                        property alias tableVerticalBar: categoryVerticalBar

                        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                            id: categoryVerticalBar
                            policy:ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
                        }

                        model: CategoryTable {}

                        delegate: Rectangle{
                            border.color: "gray"
                            border.width: 0.5

                            Button {
                                id:category_btn
                                width: 70
                                height: 50
                                text: categorytabledata
                                font.pointSize: 9


                                onClicked: {
                                    saletext2.text = categorytabledata
                                    //wwwindow.close()
                                    qmlSignal(categorytabledata)

                                    //salelistwindow.show()

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

For example, I want to display 10 digits in the table view when button 1 is clicked and 20 digits when button 2 is clicked.

In my code, when a button corresponding to the category of convenience store is clicked, for example, beverage, I want to receive only product information corresponding to the beverage category in the product table and print it on the table.

It works fine until I get it from the db, but I don't know how to call the table again...

Comment: if you reset the internal model data you have to follow the [model documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#modelReset), i.e. the sequence should be like this: `beginResetModel()` -> `changing data` -> `endResetModel()`. After data will be changed the model emiit a `modelReset()` signal and your `TableView` will be revalidated.

Comment: Does modelReset use a signal slot? Even if I search, only beginResetmodel and endResetmodel come up..

Comment: you shouldn't use `modelReset` it will fire automatically. just enclose your changing with beginResetModel/endResetModel pair.

Comment: Even if I put beginResetModel and endResetModel in the code, the table view is not called again. Is there any other way to call the table view again?

Comment: That's a way, you probably do something wrong. I advice you to check some Qt example or to post updated code here